# Hibernate hasMany / belongsTo structure

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am currently running Grails 2.3.3 with 'in memory' H2 database.

Where does H2 keep the Ids of all the children instances of a "hasMany"/"belongTo" condition.

I believe there must an additional storage place over and above the column that stores the parent Id in the child domain model.

I assume this because I need to run a removeFrom command prior to deleting a child directly from its domain model.

For example:

A parent domain model has a hasMany construct:

```
static hasMany = [ videoCatDataHM: VideoCatDataShr]
```

the child domain has a complimentary 'belongsTo' construct:

```
static belongsTo = [ vidCatAdminBT: VideoCatAdminShr]
```

There is a column in the child domain model called VID_CAT_ADMIN_BT_ID that correctly stores the Ids of the parent.

Prior to running a delete on a child instance I have to run this removeFrom command:

```
vidCatAdminId.removeFromVideoCatDataHM(videoCatDataShrInstance)
```

This suggests that the parent holds additional records of all the hasMany children linked to it separately from the Ids held in the child DM.

As suggested I have added Hibernate logging to this application - here are the non-select (that is DM changing ) logs are:

> Hibernate: update video_cat_admin_shr set version=?, description=?, name=?, organbt_id=? where id=? and version=?
>
> Hibernate: delete from video_cat_data_shr where id=? and version=?

The update is updating the parent instance (presumably via the removeFrom call  ) and the delete is deleting the child instance. Viewing the parent instance via the dbconsole before and after the delete shows that the only change to the parent instance is that the version number of the instance is incremented by one.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this has nothing to do with H2, it would be the same in any relational database managed by the Hibernate GORM implementation.

In this case you've defined a bidirectional one-to-many, so you've answered your question - it's the column in the child table corresponding to the "owner" property, in this case `VID_CAT_ADMIN_BT_ID` from `VideoCatDataShr.vidCatAdminBT`.

But there isn't any collection of child ids stored in the database, but rather the ids are queried as needed, essentially

```
select VID_CAT_ADMIN_BT_ID from video_cat_data_shr where id=?
```

where the ? is the id of the owning `VideoCatAdminShr` instance. This query will find all child records linked back to the parent using this foreign key. Turn on SQL logging to see the actual queries used.

Comment: How do I turn on SQL logging?

Comment: Configure logging for `org.hibernate.SQL` at the DEBUG level, or use logSql=true to just dump everything to the console (see  https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource)

Comment: I have turned on logging and the only hibernate logs that indicate a change the domain model instances are an update (presumably triggered by the "removeFrom" command) to the parent instance and a delete of the child instance. Have added the logs to my initial question above.

Comment: Yes, Hibernate bumps the version of the containing instance if you change/add/remove something in a collection. The collection is a property, so the owner is considered to have changed

Comment: That makes sense - I still don't see in dB terms what the 'removeFrom' does other than tweak the parent instance as shown in the hibernate logs. But I know if the 'removeFrom' is not part of the delete process the attempt to delete the child instance fails.